# Div placement needs to be change according responsive view?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Div placement needs to be change according responsive view, Without using insertBefore and insertAfter, is there any solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate (possibly with sketches of what you are after or some code)

Comment: Yes, there are some solutions. Which one(s) have you tried?

Comment: Can we see your sample code and the attempts you've made in jQuery?  Hint: jsfiddle.net is a great way to communicate on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a big fan of using CSS @media calls. Place elements where you want them, and hide them as appropriate.  http://jsfiddle.net/1g27my2m/  Its not exactly what you asked for, but it will accomplish essentially the same goal (from the customer's viewpoint), and you don't have to use any javascript or jQuery.

```
<div class="display_mobile"> hello there, mobile phone user </div>
<div class="display_desktop"> hello there, desktop user </div>

<style>
    @media (max-width: 420px) {
        .display_mobile{
            display: block;
        }

        .display_desktop {
            display: none;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 421px) {
        .display_mobile{
            display: none;
        }

        .display_desktop {
            display: block;
        }
    }
</style>
```